# How to redirect user requests to the closest GAE datacenter (US or EU)?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I have an application deployed both in the United States and in the European Google App Engine datacenters. (my-app-us and my-app-eu)

How can I redirect the user to the closest datacenter based on their location? The objective is to obtain the best latency.

A French user should be redirected to the EU datacenter wheras a Canadian user should be redirected to the US datacenter.

**EDIT**  Latencies given by Pingdom:

- Users in European coutries to US datacenter: ~300 ms
- Users in European coutries to EU datacenter: ~60 ms
- User in USA to US datacenter: ~50 ms
- User in USA to EU datacenter: ~300 ms

Comment: Google should be doing this automatically, don't worry about it. The whole point of App Engine is to let you forget about the infrastructure.

Comment: Also these are two separate application data stores (assuming your using datastore). If it's the same application, you may also be in violation of the terms of service.  You aren't supposed to run to independent but identitical apps to reduce you spend.

Comment: @Linuxios Google does not load balance between the US and the EU datacenters. Maybe they will add this feature in the future?

Comment: @TimHoffman True. I need check this with Google. Both applications are linked to the same Premium account so maybe there is workaround.  Thanks for the point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want this routing to be transparent to both users and applications. If that is true, DNS routing can be an option. Here's an example provider:http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/global-traffic-director/

Most DNS providers offer something like this. The main downside is that like stated in the comments, if data is not replicated and your user travels, the experience won't be great.

Comment: This is a good start. I'm surprised there is no a OOTB service from Google.